# Can you suggest a Macbook Pro recommendation for programming?

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

I was wondering if anyone out there had insights or recommendations about doing programming on Apple's portable machines. I'd like to start learning Objective-C and iPhone development, so other laptops aren't being considered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an especially powerful Mac to start learning Mac programming. Any of the just-announced MacBook Pro machines will work well. As with so many things, more RAM will always be better. On the new machines, upgrade to the max 8 GB of RAM. You'll find that you can purchase the RAM upgrade from the base 4 GB to 8GB significantly cheaper from third-party vendors, rather than from Apple.

You'll want to join the [Apple Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/) (optional, but not if you're at all serious about programming for iOS or the Mac) and install the Developer Tools from the Mac OS X Install disk.

Comment: The Apple Developer Program is free, but there are paid options as well with access to support (at least before they reduced prices) and prerelease software. As a member, you can download never versions of the developer tools.